# passing variable date with fixed time to a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function which accepts two arrays, and a date. The function uses the date
in a way where I want hardcoded values of time (with timezone) which are already stated in the function body (in the orig_dataset CTE). Here is my function so far:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION f_loop_in_lockstep_final(_id_arr int[], _counter_arr int[], d_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (uc_name_ varchar)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  
$func$
DECLARE
   _id int;
   _counter int;
  d_date date; 
BEGIN
   FOR _id, _counter IN 
      SELECT *
      FROM   unnest (_id_arr, _counter_arr) t  
   LOOP
   
   
   
   RETURN QUERY

      

with orig_dataset as (

select routes
from campaign_routes cr  
where cr.created_at between 'd_date 06:00:00 +05:00' and 'd_date 18:00:00 +05:00' 
)


-- a couple of further CTE's result in a final CTE called final_cte

select * from final_cte;


END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

When I use the following function call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_loop_in_lockstep_final('{454,454}'::int[]
                               , '{2,3}'::int[], to_date('2023-01-17','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I receive the following error:

```
SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "d_date 06:00:00 +05:00"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function f_loop_in_lockstep_final(integer[],integer[],date) line 14 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 13.6 (Ubuntu 13.6-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously `'d_date 06:00:00 +05:00'` is not a valid date literal.

You need to *add* a time value to the variable to create a `timestamp` value based on that:

```
where cr.created_at between d_date + '06:00:00 +05:00'::time
                        and d_date + '18:00:00 +05:00'::time
```

I am not entirely sure that using a time zone offset in a `time` constant works correctly, so maybe you need:

```
where cr.created_at between ((d_date + '06:00:00'::time) at time zone '+05:00')
                        and ((d_date + '18:00:00'::time) at time zone '+05:00')
```

Comment: Using the first code snippet does not result in an error, but returns an empty result set which indicates timezone not working correctly. Using the second code snippet results in SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "at"

Comment: @analyst92: the complete expression must be enclosed in parentheses for BETWEEN. I have edited my answer.

Comment: with either code snippet, an emply result set is being returned :( When I hardcode the value of datetime in the function, then correct result set is returned. this is quite confusing :(